# XSLT: Apply only one of multiple matching templates?

Tags: xml, xslt

I can't find any examples like this in my XSLT book, but then, I don't really know what to look for. I've tried googling it, but I don't really know how to formulate the search terms. I'm trying to treat `<p>` nodes differently depending on the parent. Here's my xml, hugely simplified.

```
<body>
  <p>consequuntur magni dolores eos</p>        <!-- Needs one LF -->
  <p>numquam eius modi tempora</p>             <!-- Needs two LFs -->
  <ul>
    <li><p>aliquam quaerat voluptatem</p></li> <!-- Needs one LF -->
    <li><p>quis nostrum</p></li>               <!-- Needs two LFs -->
  </ul>
  <some><arbitrary><path><p>qui dolorem ipsum</p></path></arbitrary></some>
</body>
```

I'm doing just fine with the non-arbitrary `<p>` nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="body/p[1] | li/p[1]">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body/p[position() > 1] | li/p[position() > 1]">
    <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

But I also need a template for the arbitrary `<p>`, and that's where I get into trouble: `<xsl:template match="p">` gets applied to the body and li `<p>` nodes also.

It seems the most straightforward way would be to somehow get the processor not to apply the arbitrary `<p>` to everything, but I can't figure out how to do that. I thought perhaps could add something like `*[not(self::body)]/p | *[not(self::li)]/p` to my arbitrary template, but that's a union, and I can't figure out how to get an intersection. I've seen some methods out there, including Michael Kay's, but I can't make sense of the notation, and anyway, I'm not sure that's the best (correct?) way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting all `p` elements except for those which are direct children of `body` or `li` elements can be realized by a single predicate.

> *[not(self::body)]/p | *[not(self::li)]/p

was quite close, but the `|` is not an or-operator but rather a union as you pointed out. So selecting all `p` elements and checking if they are not a child of `body` and not a child of `li` succeeds.

```
<xsl:template match="p[not(../../body) and not(../../li)]">
    <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Applying DeMorgan this could be simplified to

```
<xsl:template match="p[not(../../body or ../../li)]">
    <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are likely looking for the `priority` attribute.  You can e.g. use

```
<xsl:template match="p" priority="1">
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="body/p[1] | li/p[1]" priority="2">

<xsl:template match="body/p[position() > 1] | li/p[position() > 1]" priority="2">
```